# Changes I make to my extension controllers do not apply in the application. What's that about?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radiant

I'm using the common radiant extension, Mailer, and no changes whatsoever I make to the controller effect the application. I can in fact delete the entire controller, and it will still run flawlessly. I wish all my applications worked like that!

What am I missing to be able to alter the way this application works?

I do not have a duplicate of this running as a gem in my environment file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of "late to the party", but:

The mailer extension has a config setting Radiant::Config['mailer.post_to_page?']

Depending on that, the mailer form will post to the page itself, or to the MailController.
When posting to the page, the controller will indeed not be used.
Instead, page.process_with_mailer will be called.
See [lib/mailer_process.rb](https://github.com/radiant/radiant-mailer-extension/blob/master/lib/mailer_process.rb#L9)